# Is it okay to install a curtain rod into drywall after drilling a few accidental holes a few centimeters away?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-anchor

I should have bought a stud finder from the beginning but here I am now. I'm worried that the drywall/anchor won't be able to hold up the curtain rod because of the nearby holes I've drilled. I feel like I am seeing cracks on the wall too. I do plan to patch up the anchor holes with joint compound. If I am thinking correctly, patched up drywall cannot be drilled into again. Ended up getting a $13 zicron stud finder, I hope it's reliable for the few jobs I need it for. I appreciate any response regarding my post.[image]

here are are 2 more pictures of my situation: https://imgur.com/a/mql17Pm

Comment: Are you anchoring to the stud (with a wood screw), or to the drywall itself (with a hollow wall anchor)?  If it's the stud, or window header, then no problem with the extra holes.  Just patch up the ones you don't need.

Comment: That hairline crack is just a settlement crack.  For stuff like curtain rods(that might be pulled on), I prefer screwing into studs.  Drywall might hold, but studs should be close enough to use.

Comment: And just an FYI.  When trying to locate a stub by drilling holes, use the smallest (1/8") drill you can to avoid having to fill bigger holes.

Comment: what anchors will you use, know that drywall does not hold much

Comment: If two holes at the right side did not hit stud, then you just missed the stud.  The top red arrow should almost be perfectly on the stud.

Comment: If you fill the holes with wood filler or paintable caulk ([or joint compound, carefully applied](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/114367/5453)), there's no reason you can't re-drill them - but of course, as others have pointed out, a stud would be better.

Comment: What @crip659 said… maybe use longer screws on an angle (pointing toward the left holes) in the right hand holes.

Comment: Statistically, between _44 and 72 percent of all curtain rods in North America_ are installed with at least one set of "practice holes".  Stud finders aren't all that useful here. There's going to be a stud along the edge of the window. It's how they're built. Once you find the stud, fill the _extra_ holes and apply a dab of paint if you have it.